# Why is my javascript not triggering when using Turbolinks, even with the correct event listener?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I have run into these issues before, so I know I need to listen to a specific event to trigger my javascript that's rendered on a page. I'm trying the following, but when using a Turbolink to get to this page, the JS isn't working:

```
:javascript
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
    alert('hello')
  })
```

So whenever I type the URL, I refresh the page, or come via a redirect, this works fine. As soon as I come into the page via a (turbo)link it is not. I'm a bit lost, because this exact event listener is how I read it in the docs: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#observing-navigation-events

Comment: I've not been able to reproduce this. Are you able to demonstrate the problem with a link to a live demo?

Comment: I found that the reason was actually because I'm injecting a script to the head of the document at the top of my template. So the turbolinks:load is triggering, but the funciton I'm calling is not available in that context. I might need to write a separate question about it.

Answer (score -1):

$(document).ready(function() {

//Your code here

});

Instead of using turbolinks:load. Did you try using this instead?

Comment: Kind of depends what the original poster is trying to accomplish exactly whether this is a good option or not.

Comment: This won’t work, since turbolinks doesn’t trigger Document ready.